# bash to use "find" command and delete the user's pattern(using special arguments)

Tags: linux, bash, find, arguments

I wrote a simple bash as you see:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
   echo "Usage: ./rm.sh <global-path> <pattern>"
   exit 1
fi

for file in $(find $1 -name '$2')
do
   rm -f $file
done
```

when user write in terminal:

```
./script.sh /tmp *~
```

the script doesn't work...how to tell the script such arguments?

Thank you

Comment: It's not entirely safe to iterate over the results of `find` like this. `find "$1" -name "$2" -exec rm -f '{}' \;` is preferable.

Comment: what is the role of '{}' and \ here?

Comment: `{}` is a placeholder for the file name produced by `find` in the given command; `\;` (escaped to prevent the shell from processing it) is passed as the final "argument" to `-exec` to indicate the end of the command that `find` should run on each file it finds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must quote the argument to prevent `bash` from expanding the pattern before you can pass it to the `find` command:

```
./script.sh /tmp '*~'
```

If you don't want to quote it, you must turn off file name generation first:

```
set -f
./script.sh /tmp *~
set +f   # To turn file name generation back on
```

In your script, you need to use double quotes around `$2` so that it will expand to the given pattern before passing the value to `find`. You should really quote `$1` as well so that any directory name, even one containing whitespace, can be passed as an argument.

```
find "$1" -name "$2"
```

Comment: just a question: set -f didn't work///can you explain it more? thank you

Comment: set -f | ./script.sh /tmp "*~" | set +f

Comment: `set -f` only applies to the current shell; the pipeline runs `script.sh` in a different shell than the one you run `set -f` in. `set -f; ./script.sh /tmp *~; set +f`, however, should work.